# How to connect multiple peripherals to central node using Xcode CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am trying to connect multiple peripherals nodes to the app which serves as the central brain of the system. There are a total of 3 peripheral nodes. The nodes have been tested individually and each can connect to the user application with no complications.

The complications arise when I try to connect multiple peripherals to the app. Only one will peripheral will connect at any given time and the system won’t stop receiving data to make another peripheral connection.
I have made an array of peripherals and have tried appending each scanned peripheral into it. The problem is that for whatever reason, only one peripheral is saved.

The code I’ve attached  has been reverted back to connecting to a singular peripheral variable with the array of peripherals simply appending for now. My attempts at connecting to multiple peripherals have been total fails.

Can someone please help me connect multiple peripherals to the application?

```
nodeService1 = CBUUID(string: "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
let rxUUID = CBUUID(string: "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
let txUUID = CBUUID(string: "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
let nodeService2 = CBUUID(string: "6E400004-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
let txUUID2 = CBUUID(string: "6E400006-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //node 1 labels
    @IBOutlet weak var accelXLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var accelYLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var accelZLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gyroXLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gyroYLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gyroZLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var magXLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var magYLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var magZLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lisXLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lisYLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lisZLabel1: UILabel!

    //node 2 labels
    @IBOutlet weak var accelXLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var accelYLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var accelZLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gyroXLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gyroYLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gyroZLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var magXLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var magYLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var magZLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lisXLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lisYLabel2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lisZLabel2: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var startScanButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopScanButton: UIButton!
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var firstPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
    //var peripherials[]: CBPeripheral!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        //accelXLabel1.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: accelXLabel.font!.pointSize, weight: .regular)
        //accelYLabel1.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: accelXLabel.font!.pointSize, weight: .regular)
    }

    func onDataReceived(_ dataRecv: Array<Float>, labelPlace: String) {

        switch labelPlace {

        case "x":
            accelXLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f" ,dataRecv[0])
            accelYLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[1])
            accelZLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[2])
            gyroXLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[3])
            gyroYLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[4])
            gyroZLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[5])
            magXLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[6])
            magYLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[7])
            magZLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[8])
            lisXLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[9])
            lisYLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[10])
            lisZLabel1.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[11])

        case "y":
            accelXLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f" ,dataRecv[0])
            accelYLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[1])
            accelZLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[2])
            gyroXLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[3])
            gyroYLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[4])
            gyroZLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[5])
            magXLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[6])
            magYLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[7])
            magZLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[8])
            lisXLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[9])
            lisYLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[10])
            lisZLabel2.text = String(format: "%.02f", dataRecv[11])

        default:
            //do nothing
            print("Nothing printed.")

        }

        //NSLog("X data: %x", dataRecv)

    }
}

extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

        switch central.state {

          case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")

          case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")

          case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")

          case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")

          case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")

          case .poweredOn:
            print("central.state is .poweredOn")
            if peripheralCount < 2 {
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [nodeService1, nodeService2], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: NSNumber(0)])
            }
            print("Scanning and connecting completed.")

        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        print(peripheral)
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
        firstPeripheral = peripheral
        firstPeripheral.delegate = self

        //centralManager.stopScan()
        print("Scanned new peripheral.")
        centralManager.connect(firstPeripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
      print("Connected!")
        firstPeripheral.discoverServices([nodeService1])
        peripheralCount = peripheralCount + 1
    }
}

extension ViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

      guard  let services = peripheral.services else {return}
      print("Discovered services.")

      for service in services {
        print(service)
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
      }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,               error: Error?) {

      guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
      print("Discovered characteristics.")

      for characteristic in characteristics {
        print(characteristic)
        if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
          print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
          peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
        }

        if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
          print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
          peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
        }
      }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                    error: Error?) {
        print("Value for characteristic was updated.")
        switch characteristic.uuid {
        case txUUID:
            let data = dataHandling(from: characteristic)
            onDataReceived(data, labelPlace: "x")
      case txUUID2:
            let data = dataHandling(from: characteristic)
            onDataReceived(data, labelPlace: "y")
        default:
          print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")

      }
    }
```

Comment: Delete the property `firstPeripheral` and refactor your code to work with out it. It is creating timing related problems for you as its value will change when you discover a new peripheral.  All of the delegate methods have the peripheral supplied so you don't need it in a property. You just need the peripherals in the array.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried setting the code up to be array based before but it continued to have the same problem of only connecting one peripheral. I also only know how to reference a single element of an array at a time and not all elements of array at the same time. How would you recommend going about rewiring the code for the array? Especially since connecting to the central seems to only be able to handle connecting peripherals individually one after the other and not all together.

Comment: I think I understand your confusion now; you are trying to connect to two devices at once and display each one in one of your two sets of labels, but you are trying to do this by looking at the characteristic that the data arrived on; both peripherals have the same characteristic identifier (as you would expect), so your `if` statement will always match `txUUID` - you can see it has the same declaration as `txUUID2`.  You need to use the `peripheral.identifier` to determine which peripheral the data came from.

Comment: Does this mean that even if they have different characteristics UUIDs, the program will not catch that within the switch case? Peripheral 2 has a different characteristic UUID than Peripheral 1 so I thought a switch case would work. I've tried commenting out the discovering services of the peripherals to try and establish a connection to multiple peripherals but this still did not work so I am still confused as to why I can't establish a connection with multiple peripherals. This also does not clear up the fact that only one peripherals can connect and not multiple.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the changed digit at the start of the UUID; Normally you would change the last digits in a UUID to differentiate characteristics and services from the same peripherals

Comment: Do both of your peripherals advertise the same service (`nodeService1`) but with different characteristics or do they expose different services?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `firstPeripheral` property; This property is set when you discover a new peripheral and so it will change over time.  In other delegate methods, such as `didConnect` you rely on this property, but its value could have changed.

You also have a potential problem in `didConnect` because you only discover characteristics for `nodeService1` - If your second peripheral advertises `nodeService2` then you will never discover its characteristics.

Assuming that a peripheral only exposes `nodeService1` OR `nodeService2`, I would eliminate `firstPeripheral` as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    enum Axis {
        case x
        case y
    }
    
    //node 1 labels omitted for brevity
    
    //node 2 labels omitted for brevity
    
    @IBOutlet weak var startScanButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopScanButton: UIButton!

    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var peripherals = [CBPeripheral]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func onDataReceived(_ dataRecv: Array<Float>, axis: Axis) {

        switch axis {

        case .x:
            // Label update omitted for brevity

        case .y:
             // Label update omitted for brevity
        }

    }
}

extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

        switch central.state {

          case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")

          case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")

          case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")

          case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")

          case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")

          case .poweredOn:
            print("central.state is .poweredOn")
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [nodeService1, nodeService2], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: NSNumber(0)])
            print("Started scanning.")

        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        print(peripheral)
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
        peripheral.delegate = self
        print("Scanned new peripheral.")
        centralManager.connect(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
      print("Connected!")
      peripheral.discoverServices([nodeService1,nodeService2])
    }
}

extension ViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

        guard  let services = peripheral.services else { return }
        print("Discovered services.")

        for service in services {
            print(service)
           peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

      guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
      print("Discovered characteristics.")

      for characteristic in characteristics {
          print(characteristic)
          if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
              print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
              peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
          }

         if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
             print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
             peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
         }
    }
}
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("Value for characteristic was updated.")
        switch characteristic.uuid {
        case txUUID:
            let data = dataHandling(from: characteristic)
            onDataReceived(data, axis: .x)
        case txUUID2:
            let data = dataHandling(from: characteristic)
            onDataReceived(data, axis: .y)
        default:
          print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }
}
```